# How to limit the times you press a key in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to make a game where you can shoot bullets to kill emojis. However, i can't manage to figure out how to stop spamming the space key to shoot bullets. If you keep on spamming, the game would be too easy. I am not exactly sure if I should use the sleep command or something else.Please help! thanks!

Here is my code:

```
# import everything from turtle
from turtle import *
import random
import math
#create a link to the object (creates the environment)
screen = Screen()
speed1 = 1.3
ht()
amountOfEmojis = 11
#set a boundary for screen, if touches end, goes to the other side
screenMinX = -screen.window_width()/2
screenMinY = -screen.window_height()/2
screenMaxX = screen.window_width()/2
screenMaxY = screen.window_height()/2
#establish important data for screen environment
screen.setworldcoordinates(screenMinX,screenMinY,screenMaxX,screenMaxY)
screen.bgcolor("black")
#turtle setup
penup()
ht()
speed(0)
goto(0, screenMaxY - 50)
color('white')
write("Welcome to Emoji Run!", align="center", font=("Courier New",26))
goto(0, screenMaxY - 70)
write("Use the arrow keys to move and space to fire. The point of the game is to kill the emojis", align="center")
goto(0, 0)
color("red")

emojis = ["Poop_Emoji_7b204f05-eec6-4496-91b1-351acc03d2c7_grande.png", "1200px-Noto_Emoji_KitKat_263a.svg.png", 
"annoyningface.png", "Emoji_Icon_-_Sunglasses_cool_emoji_large.png"]


class Bullet(Turtle):
  #constructor, object for a class, pass in information
  def __init__(self,screen,x,y,heading):
    #create a bullet
    Turtle.__init__(self)#clones bullet
    self.speed(0)
    self.penup()
    self.goto(x,y)
    self.seth(heading)#pointing to itself
    self.screen = screen 
    self.color('yellow')
    self.max_distance = 500
    self.distance = 0
    self.delta = 20
    self.shape("bullet")
  #logic to move bullet
  def move(self):
    self.distance = self.distance + self.delta#how fast it's going to move
    self.forward(self.delta)
    if self.done():
      self.reset()

  def getRadius(self):
    return 4#collision detection helper function

  def blowUp(self):
    self.goto(-300,0)#function that makes something go off the screen 

  def done(self):
    return self.distance >= self.max_distance # append to list

class Asteroid(Turtle):
  def __init__(self,screen,dx,dy,x,y,size,emoji):#spawn asteroid randomly
    Turtle.__init__(self)#clone itself
    self.speed(0)
    self.penup()
    self.goto(x,y)
    self.color('lightgrey')
    self.size = size
    self.screen = screen
    self.dx = dx
    self.dy = dy
    r = random.randint(0, len(emoji) - 1)
    screen.addshape(emojis[r])
    self.shape(emojis[r])
    #self.shape("rock" + str(size)) #sets size and shape for asteroid

  def getSize(self):#part of collision detection
    return self.size
  #getter and setter functions
  def getDX(self):
    return self.dx

  def getDY(self):
    return self.dy

  def setDX(self,dx):
    self.dx = dx

  def setDY(self,dy):
    self.dy = dy

  def move(self):
    x = self.xcor()
    y = self.ycor()
#if on edge of screen. go to opposite side
    x = (self.dx + x - screenMinX) % (screenMaxX - screenMinX) + screenMinX
    y = (self.dy + y - screenMinY) % (screenMaxY - screenMinY) + screenMinY

    self.goto(x,y)

  def blowUp(self):
    self.goto(-300,0)#function that makes something go off the screen 

  def getRadius(self):
    return self.size * 10 - 5

class SpaceShip(Turtle):
  def __init__(self,screen,dx,dy,x,y):
    Turtle.__init__(self)
    self.speed(0)
    self.penup()
    self.color("white")
    self.goto(x,y)
    self.dx = dx
    self.dy = dy
    self.screen = screen   
    self.bullets = []
    self.shape("turtle")

  def move(self):
    x = self.xcor()
    y = self.ycor()
    x = (self.dx + x - screenMinX) % (screenMaxX - screenMinX) + screenMinX
    y = (self.dy + y - screenMinY) % (screenMaxY - screenMinY) + screenMinY

    self.goto(x,y)
  #logic for collision
  def powPow(self, asteroids):
    dasBullets = []
    for bullet in self.bullets:
      bullet.move()
      hit = False
      for asteroid in asteroids:
        if intersect(asteroid, bullet):#counts every asteroid to see if it hits
          asteroids.remove(asteroid)
          asteroid.blowUp()
          bullet.blowUp()
          hit = True
      if (not bullet.done() and not hit):
        dasBullets.append(bullet)


    self.bullets = dasBullets

  def fireBullet(self):
    self.bullets.append(Bullet(self.screen, self.xcor(), self.ycor(), self.heading()))

  def fireEngine(self):#how turtle moves
    angle = self.heading()
    x = math.cos(math.radians(angle))
    y = math.sin(math.radians(angle))

    self.dx = self.dx + x#how it rotates
    self.dy = self.dy + y
    self.dx = self.dx / speed1
    self.dy = self.dy / speed1

  #extra function
  def turnTowards(self,x,y):
    if x < self.xcor():
      self.left(7)
    if x > self.xcor():
      self.right(7)

  def getRadius(self):
      return 10

  def getDX(self):
      return self.dx

  def getDY(self):
      return self.dy

#collision detection
def intersect(object1,object2):
  dist = math.sqrt((object1.xcor() - object2.xcor())**2 + (object1.ycor() - object2.ycor())**2)

  radius1 = object1.getRadius()
  radius2 = object2.getRadius()

  # The following if statement could be written as 
  # return dist <= radius1+radius2
  if dist <= radius1+radius2:
      return True
  else:
      return False

#adds object to screen
screen.register_shape("rock3",((-20, -16),(-21, 0), (-20,18),(0,27),(17,15),(25,0),(16,-15),(0,-21)))
screen.register_shape("rock2",((-15, -10),(-16, 0), (-13,12),(0,19),(12,10),(20,0),(12,-10),(0,-13)))
screen.register_shape("rock1",((-10,-5),(-12,0),(-8,8),(0,13),(8,6),(14,0),(12,0),(8,-6),(0,-7)))
screen.register_shape("ship",((-10,-10),(0,-5),(10,-10),(0,10)))
screen.register_shape("bullet",((-2,-4),(-2,4),(2,4),(2,-4)))
#ship spawn exactly the middle everytime
ship = SpaceShip(screen,0,0,(screenMaxX-screenMinX)/2+screenMinX,(screenMaxY-screenMinY)/2 + screenMinY)

#randomize where they spawn
asteroids = []
for k in range(amountOfEmojis):
  dx = random.random() * 6 - 3
  dy = random.random() * 6 - 3
  x = random.randrange(10) * (screenMaxX - screenMinX) + screenMinX
  y = random.random() * (screenMaxY - screenMinY) + screenMinY
  asteroid = Asteroid(screen,dx,dy,x,y,random.randint(1,3), emojis)
  asteroids.append(asteroid)

def play():
  # Tell all the elements of the game to move
  ship.move()

  gameover = False
  for asteroid in asteroids:
    r = random.randint(0, 1)
    if r == 1:
      asteroid.right(50)
    else:
      asteroid.left(20)
    asteroid.move()
    if intersect(ship,asteroid):
      write("You Got Killed :(",font=("Verdana",25),align="center")
      gameover = True

  ship.powPow(asteroids)

  screen.update()

  if not asteroids:
    color('green')
    write("You Killed the Emojis!!",font=("Arial",30),align="center")
    ht()

  if not gameover:
    screen.ontimer(play, 30)

bullets = []
#controls
def turnLeft():
  ship.left(7)

def turnRight():
  ship.right(7)

def go():
  ship.fireEngine()

def fire():         
  ship.fireBullet()

ht()

screen.tracer(0);

screen.onkey(turnLeft, 'left')
screen.onkey(turnRight, 'right')
screen.onkey(go, 'up')
screen.onkey(fire, 'space')
screen.listen()

play()
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can record the time when each keypress comes in, and store it. If the time of the next keypress is shorter than your required threshold, just ignore it. It can all be done programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```py
import time

FIRE_DELAY = 0.1 # number of seconds between bullets
LAST_FIRE = 0

def fire():
    t = time.time()
    if t - LAST_FIRE > FIRE_DELAY:
        LAST_FIRE = t
        ship.fireBullet()
```

Comment: I still don't understand how you implement it

Comment: @BarrettD Replace your fire method with that method, and put the first three lines at the top of your program.